# PHP 7 not working on windows 10

Tags: php, windows, easyphp, ampps

I have problem with getting php 7 work on windows 10.
Wierd thing is that it worked.
I have Ampps installed. As I said php 7 worked but I had to switch to php 5.6. After switching back to php 7 apache did not start.

So I downloaded easyPHP to test php 7 (ampps is closed). I have the same thing. Php 5.6 is working but when I switch to php 7 apache is not starting and no info in error log.

What could it be?

EDIT:
I've tried to run PHP7's `php.exe` from command line and got that error: No VCRUNTIME140.dll

PHP  5.6

[image]

[image]

PHP 7

[image]

[image]

No log change

Comment: do you get errors? what does 'it doens't work?' mean..

Comment: no errors in error log file

Comment: How are you _SWITCHING_ between PHP Versions

Comment: Yes. php 5.6 is working php 7 not

Comment: I've added screeshots

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found solution.
Problem was that I didn't have `Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015` installed.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

But I had to use 32bit version - `vc_redist.x86.exe` file

Comment: Saved me a loooot of time there :)

Comment: Good chance that this is going to fix my error here: https://serverfault.com/questions/937799/apache-not-starting-on-latest-windows-ampps ... busy checking